# What is the Monotouch/C# equivalent of id<SomeType> in ObjectiveC?

Tags: c#, binding, xamarin.ios

Good day,

I have:

ObjectiveC:

```c
- (void)addTarget:(id<GPUImageInput>)newTarget;
```

C#:

```
[BaseType (typeof(NSObject))]  
interface  GPUImageOutput{
    [Export ("addTarget")]
    void AddTarget(NSObject newTarget); //Suspected source of the error
}
```

results in "unrecognized selector sent to instance" when calling

```
stillCamera.AddTarget (filter);
```

and

```
GPUImage.GPUImageOutput filter = new GPUImage.GPUImageSketchFilter ();
```

while the basetype of **StillCamera** is **VideoCamera** which has the basetype **GPUImageOutput**.

**GPUImageSketchFilter** is a **GPUImageSobelEdgeDetectionFilter** which is a **GPUImageTwoPassFilter** which is a **GPUImageFilter** which is a **GPUImageOutput** which is an **NSObject** and at the same time **implements GPUImageInput**.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent for

```
 // Objective-C 
 id<FOO> xxx;
```

Is just "Foo" in C#.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're missing a colon:

```
[Export ("addTarget:")]
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I am still confused though. Could you please explain the colon?

Comment: That's just the name of the selector, in standard ObjC. The general rule is: "foo" = a method with no arguments, "foo:"  = a method with one argument, "foo:arg1:" = a method with two arguments, etc.

Comment: I see. Thank you. That explains lots of the crashes i am having :)